# How to bind a jpg file and an exe file, resulting in an "exe" file?

Tags: c#, windows

I'd like to know how to combine a JPG file and an EXE file and make a new "EXE" file preferably using C#.

Here is the scenario I'm going to do:

1. The user run my program, selects two files, an arbitrary JPG file and an arbitrary Exe file, test.jpg and test.exe .
2. User clicks "Combine" button.
3. The program combines those two selected files and outputs another EXE, say combined.exe
4. When user runs combined.exe, the image, test.jpg, is shown using default windows photo viewer AND the test.exe is also ran.

This is what a classic file binder would do.
The point of this question is to learn the internal working of binders and how they combine two different file formats.
I would be thankful if you could provide source code if possible, preferably in C#, although any other language would do.
Thanks,
Jeremy.

Comment: You can use [Self-extracting archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) to do it: just pack .exe and .jpg into one self-extracting archive, and add in the archive an autorun script which opens default windows photo viewer and runs the .exe.

Comment: mmm...Seems like the right answer. Could you please provide any source code for sfx in C#?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You're essentially posting a list of requirements.  _" if you could provide source code"_ - Sadly we are not here to write code for you

Comment: @JeremyM, you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408790/is-it-possible-to-create-a-self-extracting-archive-which-will-run-a-specific-fil

Comment: @Ilya Thank you so much for your guidance.